# Write a variable number of arguments for IF

Tags: julia

I am trying to write a function that would solve any general version of this problem:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The way I solved it for this instance was:

```
multiples = Array(Int, 0)
[ (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) && push!(multiples, i) for i in 1:1000 ]
sum(multiples)
```

I want to write a function that will take an array of multiples (in this case, [3,5]) and the final number (in this case, 1000). The point is that the array can consist of arbitrarily many numbers, not just two (e.g., [3,5,6]). Then the function should run `i % N == 0` for each `N`.

How do I do that most efficiently? Could that involve metaprogramming? (The code doesn't have to be in a list comprehension format.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very first thing that popped into my head was the following, using modulo division and a functional style:

```
v1(N,M) = sum(filter(k->any(j->k%j==0,M), 1:N))
```

But I wanted to investigate some alternatives, as this has two problems:

1. Two levels of anonymous function, something Julia doesn't optimize well (yet).
2. Creates a temporary array from the range, then sums.

So here is the most obvious alternative, the **C-style version** of the one-liner:

```
function v2(N,M)
    sum_so_far = 0
    for k in 1:N
        for j in M
            if k%j==0
                sum_so_far += k
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return sum_so_far
end
```

But then I thought about it some more, and remembered reading somewhere that modulo division is a slow operation. I wanted to see how `IntSet`s perform - a set specialized for integers. So here is another one-liner, **`IntSet`s without using any module division**, and a functional style!

```
v3(N,M) = sum(union(map(j->IntSet(j:j:N), M)...))
```

Expanding the map into a `for` loop and repeatedly applying `union!` to a single `IntSet` was not much better, so I won't include that here. To break this down:

- `IntSet(j:j:N)` is all the multiples of j between j and N
- `j->IntSet(j:j:N)` is an anonymous function that returns that `IntSet`
- `map(j->IntSet(j:j:N), M)` applies that function to each j in M, and returns a `Vector{IntSet}`.
- The `...` "splats" the vector out into arguments of `union`
- `union` creates an `IntSet` that is the union of its arguments - in this case, all multiples of the numbers in M
- Then we sum it to finish

I benchmarked these with

```
N,M = 10000000, [3,4,5]
```

which gives you

- One-liner: `2.857292874 seconds (826006352 bytes allocated, 10.49% gc time)`
- C-style: `0.190581908 seconds (176 bytes allocated)`
- IntSet no modulo: `0.121820101 seconds (16781040 bytes allocated)`

So you can definitely even beat C-style code with higher level objects - modulo is that expensive I guess! The neat thing about the no modulo one is it parallelizes quite easily:

```
addprocs(3)
@everywhere worker(j,N) = IntSet(j:j:N)
v4(N,M) = sum(union(pmap(j->worker(j,N),M)...))
@show v4(1000, [3,5])
@time v3(1000000000,[3,4,5]);  # bigger N than before
@time v4(1000000000,[3,4,5]);
```

which gives

```
elapsed time: 12.279323079 seconds (2147831540 bytes allocated, 0.94% gc time)
elapsed time: 10.322364457 seconds (1019935752 bytes allocated, 0.71% gc time)
```

which isn't much better, but its something I suppose.

Comment: I may be misreading, but I thought the OP's issue was that "the array can consist of arbitrarily many numbers".

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity (I am new to Julia), where in documentation would I find info on `any`? I don't mean now that I've seen you use it, but beforehand?

Comment: So for quick reference ABOUT `any`, type `?any` at the REPL. To "discover" it, you'd need to look in the Iterables section of the standard library: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/?highlight=map#iterable-collections, which I admit isn't the easiest thing to find. I learnt about it from seeing it in someone elses code!

Comment: Hi IainDunning, can you see any reason why my approach (in answer below) runs so much faster? The speed is so good I'm a little suspicious that I've done something stupid and am cheating somehow. I'm working in Juno if that is relevant. Cheers.

Comment: Hey Colin, as far as I can tell it is a lot faster, and correct! Its a great approach, and directly solves the |M|=2 case. Its fast because it doesn't do any module division, I suspect, and no awkward anonymous functions. I'm not sure how to write the general version of it though...

Comment: Cool thanks :-) I suspect the general version exists in the field of combinatorics but I don't know it off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is my updated answer.

Based on the benchmarks in the answer of @IainDunning, the method to beat is his `v2`. My approach below appears to be *much* faster, but I'm not clever enough to generalize it to input vectors of length greater than 2. A good mathematician should be able to improve on my answer.

Quick intuition: For the case of `length(M)=2`, the problem reduces to the sum of all multiples of `M[1]` up to `N` added to the sum of all multiples of `M[2]` up to `N`, where, to avoid double-counting, we then need to subtract the sum of all multiples of `M[1]*M[2]` up to `N`. A similar algorithm could be implemented for `M > 2`, but the double-counting issue becomes *much* more complicated very quickly. I suspect a general algorithm for this would definitely exist (it is the kind of issue that crops up all the time in the field of combinatorics) but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Here is the test code for my approach (`f1`) versus `v2`:

```
function f1(N, M)
  if length(M) > 2
    error("I'm not clever enough for this case")
  end
  runningSum = 0
  for c = 1:length(M)
    runningSum += sum(M[c]:M[c]:N)
  end
  for c1 = 1:length(M)
    for c2 = c1+1:length(M)
      temp1 = M[c1]*M[c2]
      runningSum -= sum(temp1:temp1:N)
    end
  end
  return(runningSum)
end    

function v2(N, M)
  sum_so_far = 0
  for k in 1:N
    for j in M
      if k%j==0
        sum_so_far += k
        break
      end
    end
  end
  return sum_so_far
end

f1(1000, [3,5])
v2(1000, [3,5])

N = 10000000
M = [3,5]

@time f1(N, M)
@time v2(N, M)
```

Timings are:

```
elapsed time: 4.744e-6 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.201480996 seconds (96 bytes allocated)
```

Sorry, this is an interesting problem but I'm afraid I have to get back to work :-) I'll check back in later if I get a chance...

Comment: Oops, didn't read question carefully enough before diving in. Updating answer now.